# Git Ignore File - How

Tags: git, ignore

I just want to ignore one file.
I did this in the same dir as the file: git rm --cached [file name]

And I get fatal: path spec '[file name]' did not match any files.

I have searched numerous answers to this but none make any sense. There seems to be discussions about whether files are deleted, not deleted, removed from a tree, etc. I just want the file to not show up in the commit list in github desktop.

I did: git ls-files --others -i --exclude-standard and got a list of files that appear to be ignored already.

What is the secret to doing this?

Comment: Add it to the .gitignore file?

Answer (score 2):

For those who **don't** use graphical tools…

Add the filename to a `.gitignore` file.

In the git repo:

```
echo "path/to/file" >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Ignore that pesky file"
```

Now Git will rightly ignore that file from now on.

> Here is the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add that particular file in `.gitignore`. I assume `.gitignore` is already there in `.git/` folder.

After that `git rm --cached .gitignore`.

Comment: After I right clicked on my file and selected "ignore" it removed it but a side effect was that .gitignore then showed up in the commit list in github. I ran this command and got : rm '.gitignore' but it still shows up in commit list. ?

Answer (score -1):

Never mind, I just realized I could right click on the file in github desktop and select "ignore".